# Can't get git flow to apply to other users in Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree to work with my git repo on Bitbucket.  I would like it so that when I initialize gitflow for the repository, everyone using Sourcetree doesn't also have to initialize gitflow.  However, whenever someone clones the repo (or I delete and re-clone), I have to reinitialize gitflow.  How do I get this to stick for everyone?

If I do this with a Mercurial repository, it works fine.  Initialize HgFlow once, push, and everyone gets the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git flow stores the settings in the config file in the .git folder.  This file isn't committed to source control.  Therefore you must `git flow init` on each clone.  Because of this I tend to not deviate from the proposed branch names ... since someone is bound to forget as they clone something and screw it up.  :D

Could you store the settings elsewhere?  A few thoughts come to mind:

1. Rewrite git flow to store the settings inside a `.gitflowconfig` or similar -- good luck with that.
2. Put the gitflow settings inside the global config at ~/.gitconfig.  It's not "once and done" but it is "once per user".
3. Because git flow is just a naming convention for branches, you need not "setup" git flow to use it, you just need to perform the steps it does.  (e.g. git flow release finish merges to `master` and to `develop`.)

Comment: Thank you.  That was what I thought was happening, but I wanted to ask around and get confirmation.  I thought I might be missing something.